# How to use call http from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send an sms from my website.

Below is the HTTP api which works perfectly.It sends the msg and returns the string

```
http://sms.mywebsite.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=MYID&pass=MYPASS&sender=SENDERID&phone=1234567980&text=Test Message&priority=ndnd&stype=normal
```

But i want to use it in C#.Accept mobile number from TextBox1 and Message from TextBox2

```
 WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://sms.mywebsite.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=MYID&pass=MYPASS&sender=SENDERID&phone=" + TextBox1.Text + "&text=" + TextBox2.Text+ "&priority=ndnd&stype=normal")
```

The first statement is executing if i paste the http code directly in the website and i recieve the smsin my mobile .But the WebRequest statement dosent send the sms

```
 TextBox1.Text=123456789;//some mobile number

 TextBox2.Text="Thankyou for registering @ MyWEBSITE. A verification email has been sent to Your email";
```

Comment: Which quotes do you mean? Please clarify your question and supply more code!

Comment: what is the error/problem you're facing?

Comment: the fist line of code is executing if i paste the link in the browser.I recieve a msg.

Comment: But the second line dosent send a msg but it executes

Comment: @Melwin can you please add the whole part where you use this

Comment: You know that instantiating a `WebRequest` does not actually send the request, right? You need to call `GetRespone()` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be only creating a web request object and not executing it.

```
var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Refer to the documentation @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx

I would also recommend you use a [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Server.UrlEncode`. Probably, you have some spaces and special characters in the text message.

```
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(Server.UrlEncode("http://sms.mywebsite.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=MYID&pass=MYPASS&sender=SENDERID&phone=" + TextBox1.Text + "&text=" + TextBox2.Text+ "&priority=ndnd&stype=normal"))
```